# Change Background-Color of a Radio Button

Tags: css, radio-button, background-color

Is it possible to change the background color of a radio button input in Firefox/Chrome like in IE? (Without using images)

Run this in both IE(<9) and Firefox/Chrome:

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" /> RadioButton
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pAf3U/)

Answer (score 8):

Add this attribute to your radio input selector

```
input[type="radio"]{
  accent-color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively it is possible to change the border using CSS.

This is the input radio:

```
<input name="myinput" id="myinput" type="radio" value="1" class="highlighted" />
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.highlighted {
    outline:1px solid #F00; /* Firefox, Opera, Chrome, IE8+ */
    *filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=-1, OffY=0,color=#FF0000) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=1, OffY=0,color=#FF0000) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=0, OffY=-1,color=#FF0000) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=0, OffY=1,color=#FF0000); /* IE6, IE7 */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "no".

Even if you do manage to get something that works in one browser, browsers tend to handle form controls very differently, meaning it's nigh impossible to achieve cross-browser compatibility.

Disappointing, I know. Check out this article for more info: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200409/styling_form_controls/

Just by the way, why do you want to change the background color? Generally a radio button background will just pick up the background color of its container.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`.your-class { accent-color: red;  mix-blend-mode: multiply; }`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question bit it still comes up quite high if you google the question so here is my solution.

Style a `<label>` element that is directly after the radio button.

**HTML**

```
<input type=radio name="colour" value="green" id="colour-green" /><label for="colour-green" ></label>
<input type=radio name="colour" value="red" id="colour-red" /><label for="colour-red" ></label>
<input type=radio name="colour" value="blue" id="colour-blue" /><label for="colour-blue" ></label>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type=radio]{
    display:none;
}
input[type=radio] + label{
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    ...
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label{
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the background color of a radio button input Only in IE

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" name="custom">  
<input type="radio" name="custom">
```

**CSS**

```
input[type=radio] {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
/* This will make the border gray when the button is not checked. */
input[type=radio]:not(:checked)::-ms-check {
  border-color: gray; 
}
input[type=radio]::-ms-check {
  border-color: red; /* This will make the border red when the button is checked. */
  color: red; /* This will make the circle red when the button is checked. */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to disable the default styles provided by the browser. Then you can change the background color.

```
    input[type="radio"] {
     -webkit-appearance: none; /* For WebKit (Chrome, Safari, Opera) browsers */
     -moz-appearance: none; /* For Mozilla Firefox */
     appearance: none; /* For standard browsers */

     background: red; /* Change the background color */

}
```

Answer (score -7):

input radio is just a circle, so you can change the style of the < a > or < div > tag like this:

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/5pL8v/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But I just want to change the background of the radio button

Comment: radio button is just a **circle**, there is no text, so we can't change the background of it.

Comment: Does Anyone can give me the right solution? if not, why my answer get 4 down vote...
It's not right to telling "the truth"...