# How to change the background gray color of radio button and checkbox in wix?

Tags: bitmap, wix, radio-button

I have a radio button group and checkbox overlaying a white background bitmap. The
radio buttons and checkbox appear with what look like the default background control
color (gray). Is there a way to change the background color of these
controls to be white in wix?

Comment: is it duplicate question? like this one? [this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662650/change-background-color-of-a-radio-button)

Comment: @7alhashmi, nope, it has nothing to do with CSS - it's Windows Installer UI

Comment: @zhoulinWang Hi, what did you end-up doing for this? even if I implement the answer suggested, the corner of the radio button is still gray and looks ugly.

Answer (score 4):

Afraid not, this is a well known limitation of WiX. Basically both the checkbox and the radio buttons do not support transparency so will default to the grey background.

The workaround is to either change the background Bitmap to suit the grey background of those controls, or to Create the radio/checkbox buttons with no text, and then create transparent text labels right next to them where the text should be. The only downside is that the control can no longer be selected or deselected by clicking the text.

Here is a small example of the second suggestion applied to a checkbox control:

```
<Control Id="LaunchCheckBox" Type="CheckBox" X="134" Y="126" Width="10" Height="10" Property="LAUNCHAPPONEXIT" CheckBoxValue="1" Text=" " > 
<Condition Action="show">NOT Installed</Condition> 
</Control> 
<Control Id="LaunchText" Type="Text" X="149" Y="126" Width="170" Height="17" Text="Launch $(var.ProductNameForDisplay)" Transparent="yes" > 
<Condition Action="show">NOT Installed</Condition> 
</Control>
```