# How can I change the background color of a radio button's "circle" by CSS?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, electron

I'm developing an electron app using the react, and I must implement the radio button following the below prototype image.
As you can see, I'd like to change the background color (the color code is rgba(255,252,229,1)) of a radio button's "circle" by CSS. I googled about this, however, I couldn't find the answer...

[image]

The similar questions were changing the border and "checked" circle in a radio button.

- [Change the circle color of radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662650/change-background-color-of-a-radio-button)
- [Change Background-Color of a Radio Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120199/change-the-circle-color-of-radio-button)

I tried the below codes, but the background didn't change...
(Note: the color code I'd like to implement is rgba(255,252,229,1), but it's not clear. So, in this question, the color I'd like to implement is "green".)

- `background` and `background-color`

```css
.radio-button-input[type=radio]{
    width: 33px;
    height: 33px;

    background-color: green;
}
```

==> Not changed.

- `accent-color`

```css
.radio-button-input[type=radio]{
    width: 33px;
    height: 33px;

    accent-color: green;
}
```

[image]

===> "Checked" circle, not background circle, was changed

Comment: Do you still need help with this question?

Answer (score 7):

With CSS `accent-color` property you can only change the color of radio buttons. For your requirement you might need to restyle the radio buttons and this can be done using `appearance: none` property.

By using `appearance: none`, we can remove all browser styling from the radio button. Now, we can then use other CSS properties like background, border etc. to create our own custom radio buttons. The :checked CSS selector can be used to style the radio button in a "checked" state.

*Browser Compatibility: supported by all browsers*

```css
.input-group label{
  font-size: 2.8rem;  
}

input[type=radio]{
  appearance: none;
  width: 33px;
  height: 33px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-clip: content-box;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255,252,229,1);
  background-color: rgba(255,252,229,1);
}

input[type="radio"]:checked {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <label><input name="gender" type="radio" checked />Male</label>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <label><input name="gender" type="radio" />Female</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! Can I fill the "checked" white part with `rgba(255,252,229,1)` as the border and background remains black?

Answer (score 0):

Use css [accent-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/accent-color)

```css
input {
  accent-color: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 33px;
}

input.custom {
  accent-color: green;
}
```

```html
<label> My Custom radio
<input type="radio" class="custom" />
</label>
```

Any further customisations would require building your own radio input.

Comment: Thanks, but i'd like to change the background color of circle with "not checked" state.

Comment: You might have some luck building a custom radio input here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38468320/5385381